# Почему re.sub заменяет всю строку? Как исправить?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, строки, re

Есть строка:

```py
s = \
"""trash data
2020-06-23 09:55:48.672 log1
2020-06-23 09:59:28.617 log2
2020-06-23 09:59:28.617 log3
2020-06-23 10:00:51.234 log4
2020-06-23 10:00:51.234 log5"""
```

И есть регулярка:

```py
pat = re.compile(r"^((\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}).+)$", flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

---

Почему `pat.sub(s, "_")` возвращает

```py
"_"
```

Вместо ожидаемого

```py
"""trash data
_
_
_
_
_"""
```

? На [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/x3jTNx/1) работает так, как я ожидаю.

---

Полный код:

```py
import re
pat = re.compile(r"^((\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}).+)$", flags=re.MULTILINE)

s = \
"""trash data
2020-06-23 09:55:48.672 log1
2020-06-23 09:59:28.617 log2
2020-06-23 09:59:28.617 log3
2020-06-23 10:00:51.234 log4
2020-06-23 10:00:51.234 log5"""

print(pat.sub(s, "_"))
```

Comment: `print(re.sub(pat, "_", s))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перепутал порядок аргументов. `pat.sub("_", s)` вернул ожидаемый результат

```py
"""trash data
_
_
_
_
_"""
```